# StartType not being listed when using Get-Service

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a script that checks a list of computer names for a list of known services.  It gives the status of those services and it also is supposed to list the StartType.  Is there a reason why the StartType is not being given in the output?

In the output, the PSComputerName, ServiceName, and Status columns contain data but the StartType column remains blank.

```
$myServices = $PSScriptRoot + "\services.txt" # $PSScriptRoot references current directory
$myServers = $PSScriptRoot + "\servers.txt"
$Log = $PSScriptRoot + "\svclog.csv"

Remove-Item -Path $Log

$serviceList = Get-Content $myServices

$results = Get-Content $myServers
Invoke-command -ComputerName $results -ScriptBlock {
Param($serviceList)
    Get-Service $serviceList | Select -Property ServiceName, Status, StartType
} -ArgumentList $serviceList,$Null | Select -Property PSComputerName, ServiceName, Status, StartType |
Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $Log
```

I have tried it on Version 5 build: 14409 Revision: 1012
&
Version 5 build: 10586 Revision 117

Comment: Try wmi (Win32_Service)

Comment: Of course Win32 classes are supposed to be deprecated at some point so maybe Get-CIMInstance -ClassName CIM_Service? (I still use Win32 classes all the time anyway...shhh...don't tell anybody.)

Comment: @EBGreen until win10 & svr16 are used everywhere, I don't see them going away yet, but I do agree with utilizing CIM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Get-Service` cmdlet may not return the `StartType` property, but wmi does house that information.  This should work for you:

```
ForEach ($Service in $myServices)
{
    Get-WmiObject -ComputerName @(Get-Content -Path $myServers) -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name='$Service'" |
        Select-Object -Property PSComputerName, ServiceName, Status, StartType |
        Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $Log -Append
}
```

---

Update to use `Invoke-Command`:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $results -ScriptBlock {
    ForEach ($service in $using:serviceList)
    {
        Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name='$service'" |
            Select-Object -Property PSComputerName, Name, Status, StartMode
    }
} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $Log
```

Comment: I'm getting an "Invalid query "select * from Win32_Service where Name='c:\mypath\services.txt" error.  Any ideas?  Is there a way to incorporate this with the invoke command?

Comment: I tested this and it actually doesn't provide the Service Name or the Start Type in the output of the csv.  I'll play with the script some more.

Comment: @KadeWilliams Updated again. I was copy/pasting what you had in your statement, but it's correct now

Comment: This works.  Do you happen to know if there is a way to check for names with a wildcard in my service list?  WmiObject seems to skip over names with * in them.  Previously, I could put something like at* in the list and it would find any service that started with "at".

Comment: @KadeWilliams Yes, replace them with `%` and in the filter, use `Name LIKE '$service'` instead of `=`.  The filter uses what is called WQL if you want to look into it further.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that the Status displays OK no matter what.  I turned the service office and the scan says that it is still OK.

Comment: @KadeWilliams You're probably looking for the `State` property.  `Status` is for svc errors.