# Determine the Service.StartType in powershell 2.0

Tags: powershell, windows-services, powershell-2.0

Can we get `Service.StartType` in PowerShell 2.0?

`Service.StartType` in PowerShell 5.0 works, but in PowerShell 2.0 doesn't yield result.

```
$Service = Get-Service WinMgmt
$Service.StartType
```

I need the `Service.StartType` in PowerShell 2.0.  Is there any option?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [StartType not being listed when using Get-Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49369069/starttype-not-being-listed-when-using-get-service)

Comment: I believe what you are trying to ask is how to get the `Dot referencing` to work in powershell 2.0. I am not aware of a method to do that. Dot referencing was introduced only in PS 3.0. You can still use `$Service | Select-object StartType` to see the value. or the `-ExpandProperty StartType` on the `Get-Service` cmdlet but thats about it. Hard to use that in a script though, since the result still looks like a table.

Comment: @RohinSidharth dot referencing object members is most certainly available in PowerShell 2.0. Are you thinking of _member enumeration_ with the dot reference operator as introduced in PowerShell 4.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query the corresponding [WMI class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-service):

```
$winMgmtService = Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Filter "Name = 'WinMgmt'"

# This will be either "Auto", "Manual", "Disabled" or "Unknown"
$winMgmtService.StartMode
```

Comment: You have `Get-Service` instead of `Get-WmiObject` or `Get-CimInstance`.